# why labels are not using the whole with of form

Tags: html, css

I have this very simple form, but I'm having problems with the css. Somehow the 3 labels are not expanding all the way to the left (border of form).
html code

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Form Validation</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery_lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="animation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
    <script>


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Insert your content here -->
    <h1>The Form</h1>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Who Are You?</li>
            <li class="fields">
                <label>*First Name:</label><br/>
                <input id="firstName" class="req" type="text" /><br/>
                <label>Last Name:</label><br/>
                <input id="lastName" type="text" /><br/>
                <label>*Email:</label><br/>
                <input id="email" class="req" type="text" /><br/>
            </li>
            <li class="title">Where Are You?</li>
            <li class="fields">
                <label>City:</label><br/>
                <input id="city" type="text" /><br/>
                <label>*State:</label><br/>
                <input id="state" class="req" type="text" /><br/>
                <label>Country</label><br/>
                <input id="country" type="text" /><br/>
            </li>
            <li class="title">What Do You Do?</li>
            <li class="fields">
                <label>*Occupation:</label><br/>
                <input id="occupation" class="req" type="text" /><br/>
                <label>Company:</label><br/>
                <input id="company" type="text" /><br/>
                <label>Location:</label><br/>
                <input id="location" type="text" /><br/>
            </li>           
        </ul>
        <input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the css

```
/* form validation styling */

* {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
    /*background: #ddd;*/
}

h1 {
    background: brown;
    width: 500px;
    /*height: 100px;*/
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

#myForm {
    width: 500px;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #eee;
    /*margin: auto 0;*/
}

li.title {
    line-height: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #5A893C;
    border-top: 1px white solid;
    border-bottom: 1px white solid;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

li.fields {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;

}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

#button {
    margin: 0px auto 10px 40px;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That simple, you did not set/**reset the padding** that the browser is adding by default to `UL` elements

```
ul{
  padding:0;
}
```

[BEFORE](http://jsbin.com/soxap/2/edit) → [AFTER](http://jsbin.com/soxap/1/edit)